# Automatically spot piecewise regression breakpoints in data

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am tasked with, for instance, with the following data:

[image]

(the axes are unimportant, nor what the data represents for my question). Assuming my degrees of freedom are such that when curvefitting I don't expect to model anything higher than with polynomials of degree 3, and typically they should all be linear.

The proper fit to the data apparently looks like this:

[image]

However, I only managed to fit these two lines because I arbitrarily noted that there seemed to be a break in the qualitative behavior of the data (going from roughly constant to roughly linear) at the point indicated in my graph where the line changed its slope, as chose the models to be linear arbitrarily

Is there some way this could be done without a priori knowledge? I am trying to code a program which automatically opens up a data file and picks out the point between 2 curvefits. I'm looking for guides or explanations or anything like that that would give me the knowledge of how to find the point between 2 different curvefits or models, and then chooses the appropriate model (with the appropriate polynomial degree) for each section of the data.

I think my question essentially is asking how I can learn piecewise regression.

### Addendum

James Philips's answer looks to be what I'm looking for, however what I need to now understand is how the code works. I will now note my confusions with it, as the answering of this questions now will rest on how to understand the workings of the code.

```
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)
```

1. What exactly is `val`? Why are we using a sum of squared errors, and not a mean for instance?

`def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds`

```
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)
    slope = 10.0 * (maxY - minY) / (maxX - minX) # times 10 for safety margin

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for breakpoint
    parameterBounds.append([-slope, slope]) # search bounds for slopeA
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for offsetA
    parameterBounds.append([-slope, slope]) # search bounds for slopeB
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for offsetB


    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x
```

Isn't this just asking for the x and y data, and then creating an array called `parameterBounds` that just adds to it 1x2 arrays encoding the mins and maxs of x and y respectively, and two arrays with slope in them.

1. Why are there `[-slope,slope]` arrays being appended to "search bounds for slopeA" and "search bounds for slopeB"? Why is it constructed using the max and mins of x and y? Are they guesses as to find the proper slopes of each piece?
2. What is the 10 doing there, and why is it for "safety margin"?
3. Isn't `differential_evolution` used to find the minimum of a multivariate function? What is it exactly doing?

   `modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters)`

   `absError = modelPredictions - yData`
4. How come `xData` and `*fittedParameters` fulfill the number the required arguments for `func`?

Finally, how does this code find the breakpoint?

Comment: "proper" fit is pretty arbitrary, depending on what you are trying to achieve.  For simple prediction perhaps that works, but if your goal is inference it would be hard to justify this model without a good reason

Comment: for choosing a model with appropriate polynomial degree you might consider looking into AIC (adjusted-AIC) or BIC, avoid any statistics that simply get better with higher orders, eg. R2

Comment: I chose a cost function I am familiar with, sum-of-squared-errors, although the genetic algorithm can use any cost function. "val" is used internally in the cost function as model predictions - perhaps "predicted" is a better name. The asterisk in "*fittedParameters" expands the fitted parameters array into the individual items, standard Python syntax. The breakpoint is fitted by the genetic algorithm just as  all of the other parameters are fitted, this is one of the extremely convenient things about using this standard scipy module.

Comment: I think your question is too broad.  You haven't specified if the function should be continuous or not.  Maybe your looking for something like spline regression, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_adaptive_regression_spline

Comment: They are a lot of examples of piecewise regressions in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf . The method of calculus of the breakdown points is explained. The piecewise regression which seems convenient in the case represented on your graph is treated pp. 12-13. Posting your data instead of a figure would enable to show how applying the method in practice.

Answer (score 3):

Here is example code fitting two different straight lines to a data set, and also automatically fitting the breakpoint between the two lines. This example uses the standard scipy differential_evolution genetic algorithm module which uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, requiring bounds within which to search. In this example those bounds are taken from the data max and min values.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData = numpy.array([19.1647, 18.0189, 16.9550, 15.7683, 14.7044, 13.6269, 12.6040, 11.4309, 10.2987, 9.23465, 8.18440, 7.89789, 7.62498, 7.36571, 7.01106, 6.71094, 6.46548, 6.27436, 6.16543, 6.05569, 5.91904, 5.78247, 5.53661, 4.85425, 4.29468, 3.74888, 3.16206, 2.58882, 1.93371, 1.52426, 1.14211, 0.719035, 0.377708, 0.0226971, -0.223181, -0.537231, -0.878491, -1.27484, -1.45266, -1.57583, -1.61717])
yData = numpy.array([0.644557, 0.641059, 0.637555, 0.634059, 0.634135, 0.631825, 0.631899, 0.627209, 0.622516, 0.617818, 0.616103, 0.613736, 0.610175, 0.606613, 0.605445, 0.603676, 0.604887, 0.600127, 0.604909, 0.588207, 0.581056, 0.576292, 0.566761, 0.555472, 0.545367, 0.538842, 0.529336, 0.518635, 0.506747, 0.499018, 0.491885, 0.484754, 0.475230, 0.464514, 0.454387, 0.444861, 0.437128, 0.415076, 0.401363, 0.390034, 0.378698])


def func(xArray, breakpoint, slopeA, offsetA, slopeB, offsetB):
    returnArray = []
    for x in xArray:
        if x < breakpoint:
            returnArray.append(slopeA * x + offsetA)
        else:
            returnArray.append(slopeB * x + offsetB)
    return returnArray


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)
    slope = 10.0 * (maxY - minY) / (maxX - minX) # times 10 for safety margin

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for breakpoint
    parameterBounds.append([-slope, slope]) # search bounds for slopeA
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for offsetA
    parameterBounds.append([-slope, slope]) # search bounds for slopeB
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for offsetB


    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# call curve_fit without passing bounds from genetic algorithm
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Can you explain:

`def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)
`

There are several components to this code that I'd like to get a better understanding of.

Comment: I don't understand the following things about this work:

1) The sumOfSquaredError function- its construction and its exact utility here
2)  What the differential_evolution is exactly doing, and what it's done with the arguments sumOfSquaredError, and parameterBounds. Not sure what seed is.

Comment: The genetic algorithm needs something to minimize, so I chose sum-of-squared error. I have the "ignore warnings" because the genetic algorithm might calculate some bad value - one that gives a warning - and those warnings are not useful and are safely ignored. The parameter bounds are the regions for the genetic algorithm to search within and these bounds can be generous. The scipy documentation at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html has a "Notes" section at the bottom of the page that will likely be of interest.

Comment: I'm understanding it better I think.. 

Is `[minX,maxX]` the search bounds for breakpoint because it's the bounds for x, and the value of x that minimizes is located where the breakpoint is?

By that logic, is `[-slope,slope]` the search bounds for the slope of the first curve that is 0 at the minimum?

Is `[minY,maxY]` the search bounds for the value of the offset of one of the curves that is 0 at the minimum?

Are there 2 of search bounds for offsets and slopes? to account for 2 curves?

Comment: The breakpoint is *somewhere* between minX and maX, so those are natural bounds for this parameter, and the correct breakpoint location should indeed give a minimum cost function value. Similarly, offset should also be between minY and maxY. Yes, the two curves both have a slope and offset parameter each, so there are four parameters for the two straight lines and one value for the breakpoint for a total of five parameters.

Comment: So, is your factor of 10 to your slope because it's a reasonable guess that the two lines won't have a magnitude of slope greater than 10? 

And is it essentially finding the parameters that allow for minimization of the cost function provided?

Comment: Why return `result.x` rather than `result`? And why `seed=3`?

Comment: I'm getting the error RuntimeError: The map-like callable must be of the form f(func, iterable), returning a sequence of numbers the same length as 'iterable'. Do you know why?

Comment: my "safety factor" of 10 *times* my +/- simple slope calculation gives wider search bounds. The genetic algorithm is is used to find initial parameter estimates for scipy's non-linear solver curve_fit(). Result.x is used because that is how scipy's module is coded to return the parameters. I use seed=3 to ensure the same random number generator starting point each time, so the code will take the same amount of time for each run when performance testing.

Comment: It is appearing when trying to run `geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()` and I don't know how to fix it. -- Nevermind I know what I did wrong.

Comment: What does `pcov` do?

Comment: If you look at the scipy documentation for curve_fit() at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html it says this is the estimated covariance of the fitted parameters.